# Sumatoria en Python de números en una lista

Tags: python, lista, recursión

Necesito iterar sobre una lista de listas, extraer los números enteros de ella y hacer sumatoria en Python, pero no sé cómo.

gente. Tengo otro problema ahora.
Necesito hacer lo que indica el título de mi post. Investigué un poco y como no encontré mucho, paré en implementar una función recursiva. Este bloque de código pertenece a una clase que creé:

```
def sumatoria(self, *args):
        for valor in self.almacen.values():
            if isinstance(valor, list):
                self.sumatoria(valor)
            else:
                self.lista_suma.append(valor)
                continue
        print(f'Puntos acumulados: {sum(self.lista_suma)}')
        return sum(self.lista_suma)
```

Hay dos cosas que me abruman: la primera es que el parámetro ***args** está puesto ahí porque cuando no está, el pylint me dice que hay demasiados argumentos posicionales para la llamada al método. La segunda, es que por ser una función recursiva se queda en ese bucle hasta que suelta el **RecursionError**.

La lista sobre la que quiero iterar tiene una forma parecida a esta, por poner un ejemplo (la verdad es que busco que el método funcione de manera general sin importar el tamaño de la lista o su profundidad):

> **lista = [[4, 5], [7,4], [3, 8]]**.

What should I do? :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **"El parámetro `*args` está puesto ahí porque cuando no está, el pylint
>   me dice que hay demasiados argumentos posicionales para la llamada al
>   método"**

Los linters a veces meten la pata pero ésta vez tiene toda la razón. Tienes un método de instancia y como todo método de instancia el primer parámetro es la instancia de la clase (lo que nombramos `self` por convención). Este parámetro se pasa siempre de forma automática cuando el método se llama a través de una referencia a la instancia. Por lo tanto, si llamas a tu método así:

```
mi_instancia.sumatoria()
```

realmente se está llamando así:

```
mi_instancia.sumatoria(mi_instancia)
```

El problema viene cuando haces:

```
self.sumatoria(valor)
```

dentro del propio método en la llamada recursiva, ahora el método se llama así:

```
mi_instancia.sumatoria(mi_instancia, valor)
```

por lo que necesita un argumento más además de `self`, que tu no tienes definido si quitas `*args`. `*args` permite que la lista reciba un número indeterminado de argumentos posicionales.

---

> **"Por ser una función recursiva se queda en ese bucle hasta que suelta el `RecursionError`"**

Bien, con `*args` acepta el argumento, pero si pasas la lista anidada a la llamada recursiva, pero luego en esa llamada recursiva no iteras sobre la lista pasada como argumento, sino que vuelves a iterar sobre `self.almacen.values()` nunca terminas.... Bueno si, tarde o temprano la pila se llenaría y el intérprete mismo explotaría por un desbordamiento de pila (stack overflow)... Para evitar el desbordamiento y que el mismo intérprete colapsara (y porque a Guido nunca le ha gustado demasiado la recursión... XD) Python de forma muy conservadora limita el número de llamadas recursivas a 1000 generalmente por defecto y por eso la excepción que muestras.

Para poder llamar al método simplemente con `self.sumatoria()` debes definir el método así:

```
class Tienda:
    def __init__(self):
        self.almacen = {
            "Unicornios": [5, 3, 9],
            "Sátiros": [3, 4, 0, [3, 8]],
            "Dragones": [5, 2],
            "Centauros": 7}

    def sumatoria(self, _lista=None):
        suma = 0
        if _lista is None:
            _lista = self.almacen.values()
        for item in _lista:
            if isinstance(item, list):
                suma += self.sumatoria(item)
            else:
                suma += item
        return suma
```

> ```
> >>> tienda = Tienda()
> >>> tienda.sumatoria()
> 49
> ```

---

Ahora bien, la recursión aunque en este caso viene de perlas tiene la limitación del tamaño de la pila ya comentado, lo que limita la cantidad de listas anidadas que es capaz de procesar. Si quieres puedes hacer el algoritmos iterativo, una forma muy simple es usar una cola:

```
import collections


class Tienda:
    def __init__(self):
        self.almacen = {
            "Unicornios": [5, 3, 9],
            "Sátiros": [3, 4, 0, [3, 8]],
            "Dragones": [5, 2],
            "Centauros": 7}

    def sumatoria(self):
        cola = collections.deque(self.almacen.values())
        suma = 0
        while cola:
            item = cola.pop()
            if isinstance(item, list):
                cola.extend(item)
            else:
                suma += item
        return suma
```

> ```
> >>> tienda = Tienda()
> >>> tienda.sumatoria()
> 49
> ```

Se puede usar una lista normal pero la cola tiene optimizadas las operaciones de agregado y extracción de items de los extremos. Si usas Python >= 3.8 puedes usar expresiones de asignación:

```
def sumatoria(self):
    cola = collections.deque(self.almacen.values())
    suma = 0
    while cola:
        if isinstance(item:= cola.pop(), list):
            cola.extend(item)
        else:
            suma += item
    return suma
```

Answer (score 1):

si buscas que sea recursiva, quizas te funcione de esta manera

```py
class Demo:
    def sumatoria(self, milista):
        r = 0
        for valor in milista:
            if isinstance(valor, list):
                r += self.sumatoria(valor)
            else:
                r += valor
        return r

test = [[4, 5], [7,4], [3, 8]]
d = Demo()
r = d.sumatoria(test)
print(r)
# 31
```